# How were Snape's tears able to have Pensieve abilities?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

During the battle for Hogwarts, Snape provides a sample of his tears, which are used to prove his true loyalty once and for all. He gives the instruction to place them in Dumbledore's Pensieve. How were these tears able to give forth their Pensieve abilities?

Comment: Please specify whether you mean the books or the movies. Seems like movies...

Comment: In the Harry Potter universe the power of love is a big thing. Others have answered this very well, but there's something nearly poetic about memories regarding love coming through like tears.

Comment: They weren't tears...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to *Deathly Hallows*, the substance that leaked from Snape was not tears:

> Something more than blood was leaking from Snape. Silvery blue, neither gas nor liquid, it gushed from his mouth and his ears and his eyes, and Harry knew what it was, but did not know what to do—
>
> A flask, conjured from thin air, was thrust into his shaking hands by Hermione. Harry lifted the silvery substance into it with his wand. (*Deathly Hallows* – Chapter 32)

The substance was Snape's memories; it was not tears.

It was represented as a more tear-like substance in the movie *Deathly Hallows* – Part II, but I consider the books canon, not the movies.

Answer (score 12):

It wasn't his tears, instead of pulling his memories out of his temple like it is normally done, since he had so little time and so many memories, he forced them out of his mind through any place he could.

Perhaps because they were so emotional for him, they were naturally drawn towards his tear ducts for their escape.

(Unless it went differently in the movie, which I haven't seen yet?)